# C++ popen() wrapper not working in Objective-C++ for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c++

So I made a new view based application. Changed every `.m` file to `.mm`. Created a new C++ file called: `popenWrapper.cpp` and copied the code of the "Simple Wrapper" file into the `popenWrapper.cpp`.

I then edited my Program App Delegate File to:

```
#include "popenWrapper.cpp"
```

And I also changed this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    string command = "ps -e";
    fstream fp;
    popen_cplusplus(command, result);


    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But when I run the program I get:

> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

And it also says it's type is an "Apple Mach-O linker (Id) Error".

If i comment all the content in the `popenWrapper.cpp` and comment the function out, it runs.

If you need more just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing "popenWrapper.cpp" to "popenWrapper.h" (and including the .h version of course) fixed the error.